# Maximum size of cell in hbase-default.xml for a particular table

Tags: java, hadoop, max, hbase

Is it possible to configure the maximum size of cell in hbase-default.xml for a particular table.

If possible tell me the list of ways through which we configure the maximum cell size.

```
Reference: I got this error,

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **KeyValue size** too large
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.validatePut(HTable.java:1312)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.doPut(HTable.java:941)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:908)
```

Thanks and Regards,
Hari

Answer (score 2):

Your exception is related with this conf.

```
hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize
```

You can set this in java as:

```
conf.set("hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize",value);
```

This specifies the combined maximum allowed size of a KeyValue instance. This is to set an upper boundary for a single entry saved in a storage file. Since they cannot be split it helps avoiding that a region cannot be split any further because the data is too large. It seems wise to set this to a fraction of the maximum region size. Setting it to zero or less disables the check.

Comment: Ozhang, Thank u so much for the reply, I tried this, But my expectation is, Is it possible to configure the maxsize for every table as I wish...  This is a general config rite. So If i increase the maximum size, It will impact on all the tables rite. So Anywaz to configure the maximum size for individual size.